# Removing White spaces from column

Tags: sql

I am trying to remove white spaces from the end of a column.  I have tried doing 
ritrim, rtrim(ltrim(,  ltrim(rtrim,  and replace(descript,'  ','')  My table has 600+ row and some are still returning with spaces at the end.

```
A riego de retención*
Puntuación de participación (PA) se le dara cuando sea apropiado*

Perserveres when work is difficult.                             *   
Absences affecting student's performance.                       *
```

Any other suggestions.  Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us the table definition?

Comment: also - are they spaces or tabs?

Comment: do you need to save it without space or simply select it without space?

Comment: is the "*" part of the column? the right trim would never work. Do you men remove all whitespace before * column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try checking other blank characters other that space(`' '`) tab(`'\t'`),line feed(`'\n'`),carriage return (`'\r'`), something like this(I haven't tested it):

`TRIM (' ' FROM TRIM('\t' FROM (TRIM（'\n' FROM TRIM('\r') FROM your_column）)))`